# Multidimentional Array; Foreach Over First Sub Array Only

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Basically this makes and fills out a table. It mostly does this great, except the `foreach` seems to be making a new column for EVERY subarray, and I only want a column made for each in `[heroes]`. My limited knowledge of php has forced me to come here again. I tried array_slice to try and get that to work (its at 0 now, but I tried other numbers). I also tried `$CAREER_DATA['heroes']` in the `foreach` but that just made it all worse.

Not sure how to get just the part I want out of this.

**e:** I just realized i can perhaps extract just that subarray out and have it as its own array and use a veriuable for that. Ill try that now... Id still like to know how to do it this way though.

Full array

```
$CAREER_DATA = Array
(
    [heroes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 384
                    [name] => Barbecue
                    [id] => 35335691
                    [level] => 70
                    [hardcore] => 
                    [gender] => 0
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => barbarian
                    [last-updated] => 1400233350
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 384
                    [name] => Ethereal
                    [id] => 43477852
                    [level] => 70
                    [hardcore] => 
                    [gender] => 1
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => crusader
                    [last-updated] => 1400357611
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 384
                    [name] => Aikido
                    [id] => 35213628
                    [level] => 70
                    [hardcore] => 
                    [gender] => 1
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => monk
                    [last-updated] => 1400186566
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 384
                    [name] => Euphoria
                    [id] => 45715169
                    [level] => 70
                    [hardcore] => 
                    [gender] => 1
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => demon-hunter
                    [last-updated] => 1399516194
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 384
                    [name] => Entropy
                    [id] => 47278203
                    [level] => 70
                    [hardcore] => 
                    [gender] => 1
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => wizard
                    [last-updated] => 1399595333
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 384
                    [name] => Eulogy
                    [id] => 47138988
                    [level] => 11
                    [hardcore] => 
                    [gender] => 0
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => witch-doctor
                    [last-updated] => 1400179777
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 0
                    [name] => lolwut
                    [id] => 47160915
                    [level] => 6
                    [hardcore] => 1
                    [gender] => 0
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => barbarian
                    [last-updated] => 1398282569
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 384
                    [name] => MuleWeapons
                    [id] => 47148207
                    [level] => 1
                    [hardcore] => 
                    [gender] => 0
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => crusader
                    [last-updated] => 1399596544
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [paragonLevel] => 384
                    [name] => MuleJunk
                    [id] => 47154043
                    [level] => 1
                    [hardcore] => 
                    [gender] => 0
                    [dead] => 
                    [class] => demon-hunter
                    [last-updated] => 1399596678
                )

        )

    [lastHeroPlayed] => 43477852
    [lastUpdated] => 1400357611
    [kills] => Array
        (
            [monsters] => 1296806
            [elites] => 33006
            [hardcoreMonsters] => 241
        )

    [timePlayed] => Array
        (
            [barbarian] => 1
            [crusader] => 0.261
            [demon-hunter] => 0.035
            [monk] => 0.278
            [witch-doctor] => 0.017
            [wizard] => 0.119
        )

    [fallenHeroes] => Array
        (
        )

    [paragonLevel] => 384
    [paragonLevelHardcore] => 0
    [battleTag] => Paultimate#1333
    [progression] => Array
        (
            [act1] => 1
            [act2] => 1
            [act3] => 1
            [act4] => 1
            [act5] => 1
        )

)
```

PHP/HTML:

```
<? $herokeys   = array_keys($CAREER_DATA["heroes"][0]);?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="3">
   <?php foreach($herokeys as $value): ?>
      <tr>
         <td style="background-color: #101210;"><?php echo $value; ?></td>
         <?php foreach(array_slice($CAREER_DATA, 0) as $index => $element): ?>
            <?php foreach($element as $k => $v): ?>
               <td><?php echo $v[$value]; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

[image: Yellow shows the faulty extra columns]

Comment: Please post a sample of the HTML output your current code produced, along with a sample of what you _want_ it to look like. It seems like you've overcomplicated the looping a little, to the degree that the code is hard to mentally execute :)

Comment: Most likely, this is just going to be a simple matter of a pair of nested `foreach`, no complicated slicing or variable indexing.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oFHFxwR.png

Basically I only want the part circled in red. The part in (badly done) yellow is the extra that I dont want.

Comment: I see - so you're getting a bunch of extra columns, where you want to identify the table by _row_ rather than by _column_.  Per your little edit, do you _really_ want to know how to do this using `array_slice()`?  I can say pretty confidently that nobody would ever attempt that in production code because there are easier ways.

Comment: No, I just had array_slice() in there as my own attempt to see if it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to handle this is to extract the `['heroes']` sub-array and *reformat it* to fit the structure you ultimately intend to use as output. That basically means flipping it on its side such that each *row* relates to an original key.

There are a couple of ways to handle this, but since all your hero sub-arrays have the same keys, you can build a new sideways array with a loop, then use a pair of `foreach` loops for your final output.

```
$output_array = array();
// Start with just the heroes...
$heroes = $CAREER_DATA['heroes'];
// Looping over all of them...
foreach ($heroes as $hero) {
  // And looping over each key to flip it:
  foreach ($hero as $key => $value) {
    // Initialize a new array for this key if it isn't already.
    if (!isset($output_array[$key])) {
      $output_array[$key] = array();
    }
    // Append the value
    $output_array[$key][] = $value;
  }
}
// See what it looks like now:
print_r($output_array);
```

Now the structure of `$output_array` looks more similar to your output table.  Use a series of loops to write it out.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3">
<?php foreach ($output_array as $key => $values): ?>
  <tr>
    <!-- 
     $output_array is indexed by hero property, here as $key
     so write that out first
    -->
    <td style="background-color: #101210;"><?php echo $key; ?></td>
    <!-- then a loop for each of the values for that property -->
    <?php foreach ($values as $value): ?>
    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

It can also be done using something more similar to your `array_keys()` attempt without first reformatting the array.  Call `array_keys()` to get the property names, then loop the sub-arrays. This results in less code, but without the niceness of a data structure formatted how you want it in the first place.

```
<?php $properties = array_keys($CAREER_DATA['heroes'][0]); ?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="3">
<?php foreach ($properties as $property): ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #101210;"><?php echo $property; ?></td>
    <!-- then a loop for each individual in heroes -->
    <?php foreach ($CAREER_DATA['heroes'] as $hero): ?>
    <!-- write out this individual's value for $property -->
    <td><?php echo $hero[$property]; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I'll recommend you use a CSS class instead of an inline `style` for the property names. Instead of:

```
<td style="background-color: #101210;"><?php echo $key; ?></td>
```

Add a class like:

```
<td class='propname'><?php echo $key; ?></td>
```

and define it in your CSS

```
.propname { background-color: #101210; }
```

Lastly, the reason for your extra columns looks to be an incorrect use of [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). Since you passed the main array `$CAREER_DATA` and used `0` as the offset without providing the 3rd parameter `$limit`, you end up iterating over the entire `$CAREER_DATA` array with all its keys, effectively turning the `array_slice()` into a full `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that up. I will be bookmarking this and taking it as advisement for the future. Also note that `array_slice($CAREER_DATA, 0, 1)` actually 'fixed' the issue. Im not sure if its the right way to do this but it seems to be doing what I wanted, slicing the first sub array `heroes` and using only it. Are there a reasons i shouldn't do it that way?

Also yes about CSS, everything I can possibly add to CSS i will be when I get all this worked out and can start minimizing everything. Thanks again

Comment: _Are there a reasons i shouldn't do it that way?_ As I alluded to in the comments at the top, it's really just overcomplicating things.  I would reserve array operations like `array_slice()` for when actually manipulating the contents of arrays. When you have a data structure and need to output it (especially if you need to use all of it) it is almost always possible to do with a couple of `foreach` loops, and that tends to be the most readable and understandable way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just like you did with the array_keys, get the values with array_values(.) and loop through them,

also, to get the first element of an array it's better to use

```
current($arr)
```